# HTML selected option using JavaScript does not work

Tags: javascript, html-select

The following code (in file formBuilder1.js) gives me this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null.

What can I do to solve this problem?

```
var medium = ["Luft","Wasser"];
var selectElement = document.getElementById('Medium');
for(var i=0;i<2;i++){
    var opt = document.createElement('option');
    opt.innerHTML = medium[i];
    opt.value = medium[i];
    selectElement.appendChild(opt);
```

The HTML code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>


<script src="formBuilder1.js"></script>

<select id="Medium"></select>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem is that the element you're trying to find, with the `id="Medium"` doesn't exist in the page at the point the JavaScript is trying to find it (hence the error message you're receiving). Try moving the `<script>` block to just before the closing `</body>` tag, and see if that works.

Comment: as mentioned by @DavidThomas you loading the script before the element is created ie. somewhere in header or before body move it to end of your page..also if you perform such operation on click of button or something ensure the element (here "medium") exits before you  run script..

Comment: put your script after your element `<select id="Medium"></select>`

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine, when put in a jsFiddle ( https://jsfiddle.net/vj5s165e/ ). As mentioned in the comments to your OP, you need to include your JS after the element is added to the DOM.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
    <select id="Medium"></select>
    <script src="formBuilder1.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Also consider wrapping your JavaScript in a window.onload function to prevent it being executing until the DOM is ready.https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload